# Timelapse Video Of Motion of Mars?

Tags: planet, video

I'm trying to find a timelapse video of mars moving against a fixed background of stars - could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need a real video? Otherwise it can be created with Stellarium.

Comment: Real video would be nice -> but I will check out Stellarium - thank you!